# how to check array values exists in other array vba

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've two arrays, first one is Litems(i), and second one tcols(k). How to check array Litems(i) values exists in tcol(k) array using access VBA.

Comment: Hereby nominated for "least amount of effort in a question" award. -1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following to find matching values:

```
Dim lSize1  As Long
Dim lSize2  As Long
Dim lX1     As Long
Dim lX2     As Long
lSize1 = UBound(Litems)
lSize2 = UBound(tcols)
For lX1 = 1 To lSize1
   For lX2 = 1 To lSize2
       If Litems(lX1) = tcols(lX2) Then
          Debug.Print "Match: Litems item " & lX1 & " = tcols item " & lX2 & vbTab & "Value = " & Litems(lX1)
       End If
   Next lX2
Next lX1
```

Try the following to find non-matching values:

```
Dim lSize1  As Long
Dim lSize2  As Long
Dim lX1     As Long
Dim lX2     As Long
dim blnFound as Boolean

lSize1 = UBound(Litems)
lSize2 = UBound(tcols)

For lX1 = 1 To lSize1
   blnFound = False  
   For lX2 = 1 To lSize2
       If Litems(lX1) = tcols(lX2) Then
          blnFound = True
       End If
   Next lX2
   If blnFound = False Then
      Debug.Print "No Match for: Litems item " & lX1 
   End If
Next lX1
```

Comment: How do i message the *Litems* array item name(s) if it is not found in *tcols* array